# Catching part of the url with .htaccess and change it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

I'm trying to redirect my users from old Wordpress post url:

```
example.com/al-gacho/archives/608
```

To:

```
example.com/blog/archives/608
```

All I need to do is catch /al-gacho/ and replace it with /blog/.

Can some one help? :(
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/al-gacho/(.+)$ /blog/$1
```

Make sure this is first line in your root .htaccess